# Negative R2 on Simple Linear Regression (with intercept)

Tags: regression, python, least-squares, r-squared, negative-r-squared

I am doing a simple Linear Regression (**with intercept**) which ends up presenting a **negative R2**, this should not be possible (cf comment 2 at the end)

---

### Reproducible examples of the issue:

Minimal `sklearn` reproducible code:

```py
import numpy as np; print(np.__version__) # 1.23.5
import scipy; print(scipy.__version__) # 1.10.0
import sklearn as sk; print(sk.__version__) # 1.2.1

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(8)
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(10, 1, size=1_000))

l_com = np.arange(100)
df_Xy = pd.concat([s.ewm(com=com).mean() for com in l_com], axis=1)
df_Xy['y'] = s.shift(-1)
df_Xy.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df_Xy[l_com]
y_true = df_Xy.y

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True) # fit_intercept=True by default anyways
model.fit(X, y_true)
print(model.score(X, y_true))
# -0.15802176533843926 = NEGATIVE R2 on VM 1
# -0.05854780689129546 on VM 2 (? dependent on CPU ?)
```

---

Minimal `scipy` reproducible code:

```py
import numpy as np; print(np.__version__) # 1.23.5
import scipy; print(scipy.__version__) # 1.10.0
import pandas as pd

# Parameters:
(seed, N_obs, N_feat, mu_x, sigma_x, sigma_y) = (0, 100, 1000, 100, 10, 1)

# Building very weird X,y arrays (High Colinearity)
np.random.seed(seed)
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, N_obs))
X_raw = np.ascontiguousarray(np.stack([s.ewm(com=com).mean() for com in np.arange(N_feat)]).T)
y_raw = np.random.normal(0, sigma_y, N_obs)

# Center both arrays to zero
X_offset = X_raw.mean(axis=0)
y_offset = y_raw.mean()
X = X_raw - X_offset
y = y_raw - y_offset

# OLS: Finding parameters that minimise Square Residuals:
p, _,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(X, y) # <-- This is silently Failing! (resulting parameters are worst than the zero vector)
pred = np.matmul(X, p)
RSS = np.sum(np.power(y - pred, 2)) # 108.3406316733817
TSS = np.sum(np.power(y - np.mean(y), 2)) # 107.05357955882408
```

---

- Comment 1: Yes, `X` matrix is computed in a very specific way (Exponential Moving averages of the target). It seems that the problem arises particularly well in this case. I'm currently trying to find an example without this "complexity".
- Comment 2: If you are a beginner/intermediate Data Scientist, please refrain from commenting something like "*R2 can sometimes be negative*": we are in the case of simple OLS with intercept. The Sum of Squares should be minimised, by definition.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I get an $R^2$ of 10.8%.

Comment: Correction: Actually I can reproduce this with `sklearn` version `1.2.1` but not with `1.2.2`.

Comment: @usεr11852 And I get $5.8\%$ running it in Jupyter online!

Comment: @Dave: What version of`sklearn` is it using in your case? It seems to me like `sklearn` just has a horrible time optimising this. :)

Comment: @usεr11852 I can’t tell on mobile, but it’s the Python tool [here](https://jupyter.org/try).

Comment: my Scientific Wild Butt Guess (SWAG): collinearity due to the X variables all being very similar leads to numerical issues.

Comment: You monster, I never reply on mobile. (Otherwise, my life would be fully gone.) It has 1.2.2 but a different (newer) `numpy` than mine (1.24.2 vs 1.22.4). Yeah @JohnMadden is probably right, we are just looking at different ways `scipy.linalg.lstsq` can fail.

Comment: @usεr11852 I also got 10.8% but can reproduce it with seed value 10

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: I like your versioning. (As it matches mine. :D )

Comment: Amazingly, if I change my EC2 VM instance type (different CPUs, exact same version of all packages), I get different results.
I use sklearn version 1.2.1

Comment: @JohnMadden It was my guess too.
Considering how common EWMA are in time-series forecasting, that is amazing that this problem is not better documented :(

Comment: @JeanLescut regularisation can solve the problem of highly correlated variables, and is well documented.

Comment: What I am also wondering is whether the coefficients in this forecasting are typically non-zero? (I am asking because I do not know about EWMA and time series forcasting) That constraint will also reduce the effect of the correlations between the features.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Detailed explanation of the problem:

In the case of X being near-singular (high colinearity/covariance between features), different issues where coming both from `scipy.linalg.lstsq()` and `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegession()`

**Source of error 1**: As @SextusEmpiricus explained, the matrix being near-singular leads to rounding errors that impact enormously the final predictions. In this sense, `scipy.linalg.lstsq()` is silently failing *WITHOUT* raising any warning or error.

**Source of error 2**: The matrix coming from pandas was F-contiguous. `sklearn` converts it to C-contiguous before calling `scipy.linalg.lstsq()` and then use the `predict()` by using a *matrix multiplication* right from the F-contiguous array. This lead to another layer of rounding errors. I opened [another question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388886/python-rounding-errors-between-c-contiguous-and-f-contiguous-arrays-for-matrix)

**Source of error 3**: The first thing that `LinearRegression()` is doing is to center the dataframe. This goes badly in my case, I still struggle to understand why exactly.

Note: Please note that these rounding errors also depends on CPUs and hardware, which makes it even hard to achieve reproducibility.

---

### (Partial) Work-Around:

To work around the `sklearn` problems, one can:

- Ensure input matrix/array are C-contiguous
- Stop rely on `LinearRegression`'s `fit_intercept=True` but instead center data manually first:

```py
for seed in range(1000):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(10, 1, size=1_000))

    l_com = np.arange(100)
    df_Xy = pd.concat([s.ewm(com=com).mean() for com in l_com], axis=1)
    df_Xy['y'] = s.shift(-1)
    df_Xy.dropna(inplace=True)

    X = np.ascontiguousarray(df_Xy[l_com].values)
    y = np.ascontiguousarray(df_Xy.y.values)

    X_offset = X.mean(axis=0)
    y_offset = y.mean()

    X_centered = X - X_offset
    y_centered = y - y_offset

    model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False) # We don't rely on sklearn fit_intercept anymore
    model.fit(X_centered, y_centered)
    assert model.score(X_centered, y_centered) > 0 # ALL GOOD
```

---

### Moving forward / Long-term Solution:

1. [I opened an issue in `scipy` Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/18615) to raise a Warning in `scipy.linalg.lstsq` when the X matrix is near-singular.
2. [I opened an issue in `sklearn` project on Github, about inconsistency between C-cont vs F-cont arrays](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/26493)

Answer (score 7):

I can reproduce it with `np.random.seed(15)` and dig a bit deeper. It seems a lot like a computational round-off error due to the high collinearity.

The steps I took

- I manually added a column with ones to the matrix `X`

  ```
  #X =  df_Xy[l_com]
  X = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(1, 999)),df_Xy[l_com]], axis=1)
  ```
- and used directly the function `lstsq(X, y_true)`, for which the function `LinearRegression` is a wrapper, and manually compute the sum of squares

  ```
  p, res, rnk, sin = lstsq(X, y_true)
  pred = np.matmul(X, p)
  RSS = np.sum(np.power(y_true - model.predict(X=X), 2)) ## 1007.6190
  RSS2 = np.sum(np.power(y_true - pred, 2))              ## 1007.6190
  TSS = np.sum(np.power(y_true - mean(y_true), 2))       ## 995.24937
  ```

The R-squared is still negative.

(the above is for `intercept=False` interestingly, when I set it true then the result becomes even worse, but I can't yet figure out what the [sourcecode](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py) does with that boolean parameter)

A reason for this behavior might be that the parameters are very large because you generated the coefficients with some exponentially weighting (I do not know enough about python to figure out easily what you are doing there, and you might provide more comments about your code) and created highly correlated features. The `lstsq` gives as output a very small effective rank and the coefficients are in the order of $\pm 10^{10}$.

At the moment this is as far as I can get. I find the code in python libraries difficult to decipher. The [linearmodel](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py) from sklearn refers to a function [lstsq](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/linalg/_basic.py) from scipy/linalg and that function refers to 'gelsd', 'gelsy', 'gelss' functions from lapack which is a fortran code that is somewhere but through all the layers of wrappers and imported packages it is difficult to figure out what happens in the blackbox between input and output of linearmodel.

---

#### The influence of the processor

> ```
> print(model.score(X, y_true))
> # -0.15802176533843926 = NEGATIVE R2 on VM 1
> # -0.05854780689129546 on VM 2 (? dependent on CPU ?)
> ```

In the answer to this question on stack overflow it is explained that the algorithm might take slightly different steps for different CPU architectures and as a consequence there can be small differences in results for different CPUs: [Is it reasonable to expect identical results for LAPACK routines on two different processor architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120608/)

Example: for a computer we have $(7+8) \times (1/9) \neq (7/9+8/9)$. Demonstration with R-code

```
options(digits=22)
(7/9) + (8/9) # 1.666666666666666518637
15/9          # 1.666666666666666740682
```

An algorithm might make such subtle changes in the computation to optimize the calculation speed for a processor.

In the case of a matrix inversion of a nearly singular matrix these small errors might get amplified due to the sensitivity of the computation on small differences.

(I don't have the ability to verify this with different processors, but I will check whether changing the number of cores can have a similar influence.)

Comment: Amazing, we're getting closer !
My hope here is to try to implement a check in lstsq() and issue a warning when needed. It's understandable that the function fails, but not that it fails silently...

Comment: @JeanLescut I know that `lm` in R would provide an error telling that the matrix is singular. I recently encountered a similar question for MATLAB that had different behaviours with a similar issue of matrix inversion. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616591/

Comment: You are absolutely right about CPU thing.
According to my experiments, scipy.lstsq() doesnt lead to a negative R2 though.
But the LinearRegression() code of sklearn convert X into a F-contiguous array before multiplying it with the parameters. This induces several small "errors" that actually becomes crazily bad in my case.
I will investigate deeper and maybe propose a change in the sklearn code to keep arrays C-contiguous all along

Comment: @JeanLescut I also had slightly different behaviour with `lstsq()` and changed the random seed. In your case does it also 'work' when you use `np.random.seed(15)`? And even when it works, the cause of the problem (not giving an error for problematic user input) has not been resolved. Ideally the function should give a warning when results are computationally unstable.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. As I wrote below, my next step would be to ask for said warning to be implemented.
Despite all my trials, I couldnt make lstsq() fail on my side. I'll keep investigating.
Thank you so much for your help (for me and the community !)

Comment: @JeanLescut The `scipy.linalg.lstsq()` has the same problems, but is just performing better and will make the 'error' less easily. I could make it fail with an online compiler https://onecompiler.com/python/3zadf7u39 (I believe that the link will take you to my scribble, although I am not sure whether it can change)